# Why is a set of $n$ equations in $k$ variables?

Tags: terminology, systems-of-equations

This is more of a language question, but it seems backwards to me. How is it that the equations are in the variables? My intuition tells me that that the variables are in the equations. Is it the same thing?

Comment: *Hamlet* is a play in five acts... or are the five acts *in* *Hamlet*?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork this is a helpful example when using the explanation from gt6989b thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is elliptic. The intent is to describe a set of $n$ equations, *expressed* in $k$ variables. In this context, the preposition *in* is synonymous with *via* or *through*.

Comment: Thank you! It makes much more sense now. Though now I wonder if it would be alright to say that there are $k$ variables contained by $n$ equations. Or if that is a sort of cardinal sin.

Comment: @MatthewBourgeois not cardinal sin, just a non-standard way to express a standard thing